# Specify uploaded filename

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm uploading an image using the rainlab builder plugin. Say for example the file is called "my_image.jpg"

This will get uploaded to storage/uploads/public/56f/809/658/56f809658.jpg
This isn't very seo friendly so I want it to keep it's original filename my_image.jpg

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

may be for public files you need to use `mediafinder` **widget**

as we need to store this files anyways in public space so we can use `mediafinder`

as described here by author https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/964

you can define extra `fieldname` in table like for ex: `banner(text)`

and then you can use that `field and mediafinder` combination to `achieve SEO friendly names`.

column config :

```
fields:
    ... some fields 

    banner:
        label: Banner
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        mode: file
        span: auto
        type: mediafinder
```

when you want show image you can use :

> page code section

```
use HardikSatasiya\DemoTest\Models\Demo;
function onStart() {
    $this['record'] = Demo::find(5);
}
```

> page markup section

```
<img src="{{ record.banner|media }}" alt='extra-seo-name' />
```

> **rendered out put**

```
<img src="/storage/app/media/drawing.png" alt='extra-seo-name' />
```